# Wrapping WebApi responses using DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, delegatinghandler

I'm trying to use a `DelegatingHandler` to wrap my Web API responses. I'm using [this](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/wrapping-asp.net-web-api-responses-for-consistency-and-to-provide-additional-information) as an example.

At some point the content needs to be read from the response object:

```
if (response.TryGetContentValue(out content) && ...)
```

The solution didn't work because `response.TryGetContentValue(out content)` doesn't actually return anything (or populate the `content` variable that is).

However if I 'change' the code to...

```
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>().Result;
```

... it does work.

I would expect that `TryGetContentValue` and `Content.ReadAsAsync` return the same value. Why is this not the case?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Could you confirm if TryGetContentValue returns true or false?

Comment: Could you check what is a value of Content property (and of what type) when calling TryGetContentValue?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski: it returns false

Comment: @AlekseyL.: just did that for formatting the question...

Comment: @MichałKomorowski: the type is `System.Net.HTTP.StringContent`. However when I retrieve it using `ReadAsAsync` I'm forcing it to be an object. Does this automatically deserialize it then..?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski: please see added screenshot. I tried using `TryGetValue<string>` but this still doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpResponseMessageExtensions.cs) of `HttpResponseMessageExtensions.TryGetContentValue` method you will see something like:

```
ObjectContent content = response.Content as ObjectContent;
if (content != null)
{
     ...
}

value = default(T);
return false;
```

It means that this method assumes that `HttpResponseMessage.Content` property will return an instance of [ObjectContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) type. However, in your case it is [StringContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and it cannot be casted to `ObjectContent`.

Comment: I did look at the source code, somehow I assumed `ObjectContent` as being castable to `StringContent`... Thanks!